# I want to export all the customers who used a coupon

Tags: customer, export

We recently sent out an email with individual discount codes in.

I want to now extract all of the customers that used the discount code so that we can eliminate them from our next email.

I cannot find how to export these customers, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get that info directly from admin panel but you can get it from your database.

Let's assume the ID of your cart rule is 1 and that each coupon can be used only once. The following SQL query should do the job:

```
SELECT o.customer_email
FROM salesrule_coupon c
LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order o ON ( c.code = o.coupon_code )
WHERE times_used = 1
AND rule_id = 1
```